# Remove the default style in <Pre> tag in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I pasted a microsoft word post into my wordpress post and after posting the post has a grey background and a border around it. Why did it occur and how to remove this so that this does not happen every time I paste into my wordpress post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Word puts a bunch of markup into your text.  If you look at the plain text version, you'll see it's a mess.  Use something like https://wordpress.org/plugins/mammoth-docx-converter/ to upload your Word docs to WP.  It's not perfect, but gets you cleaner markup.

Comment: I pasted the Word text directly into the plain text within the <pre> tag. The text format looks fine except the background color and the border around it. @jmargolisvt